# url Encoding %20 for spaces

Tags: swift, url-encoding

This has been asked and answered but for the life of me i can not figure it out.

```
let encodedFileName = fileName?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlPathAllowed)
let destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: cachesDirectory.appendingFormat("/\(encodedFileName!)"))
```

produces a file with this name:

```
f95c3d5fa2064759fa4c397e7b8ab1e0_The2ame                   0f        0.000000e+002ind2p3
```

the other NSCharacterSet options are similar.  what am i missing here?

All i want is %20 in place of spaces.

Comment: Works for me? http://d.pr/i/VkYQ

Comment: Change `urlPathAllowed` to `urlQueryAllowed`. Might work.

Comment: Its the same thing.  prints: 94548048b5e28646088c6ca38a69903d_The2ame%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200f%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200.000000e+002ind2p3  and saves like shown in the question